# Can't delete events in SmartWatch2

Tags: sony-smartwatch

My users are reporting a problem with deleting events after recent SW2 firmware update.

I used the following method:

```
NotificationUtil.deleteAllEvents(InformerPreferenceActivity.this, InformerExtensionService.EXTENSION_KEY);
```

Please advise

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the problem. Can you please share following information?

- SmartConnect version
- Host app (SmartWatch 2) app version
- SmartWatch 2 firmware version
and return value you are getting from this method

Comment: Ahmet, thanks a lot for respond Smart Connect: 5.7.14.218

SW2(Host): 1.6.23

Smartwatch(firmware): 1.0.B.6.32/1.0.A.11

Comment: Hi @rudakovsky: Are you able to reproduce this issue as well? If we get to know how to reproduce the problem, this will dramatically improve our troubleshooting efforts. As Ahmet mentioned, the return value from the method is also important to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Users of my app claim that only unread notifications can be deleted. Read ones still remain after notificationUtil.deleteAllEvents which returns number of events

Comment: Does it make sense to use REFRESH_REQUEST_INTENT somehow?